# CreatePopupMenu for windows 11

Tags: c++, winapi, right-click

I checked windows 11 has a new style of menu items which looks like this

[image]

Please note
**It has an icon row on top**

What modification are required in usage of **CreatePopupMenu** function (winuser.h)  for bringing the same behaviour in our app . I am unable to find the documentation link for win 11 context menu for CreatePopupMenu update. I wish to use my own icons on top and hence wanted to explore already used  CreatePopupMenu.

Some example code would really help me !

Comment: This is not related to CreatePopupMenu but to Windows 11 context menu handling: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/ *"Apps extend the menu with IExplorerCommand + app identity. Unpackaged Win32 apps can use Sparse Manifests."*

Comment: It's not a standard Win32 menu. I highly doubt there's a public API to display something that looks like that; you'll need to write it yourself.

Comment: Strange Jonathan . I thought since they used it in there menu they would have created an api too which I could leverage . Simon do we have a sample

Comment: The blog @Simon Mourier mentioned involves a [SparsePackages](https://github.com/microsoft/AppModelSamples/tree/master/Samples/SparsePackages) sample.

Comment: @JonathanPotter It's built out of a XAML CommandBar.